# I can't enable my listBox in Modern UI for WPF (vs2013 C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, blend, modern-ui

My main window is a modern tab with a group of links. Each link navigate to different page.

```
<mui:ModernTab Layout="List" Margin="0,0.5,-222,-2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="742">
    <mui:ModernTab.Links>
        <!-- TODO: set @Source -->
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Page 0" Source="Page0.xaml"/>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Page 1" Source="Page1.xaml"/>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Page 2" Source="Page2.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Page 3" Source="Page3.xaml"/>
    </mui:ModernTab.Links>
</mui:ModernTab>
```

Page 0 shows a listBox with several items.

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="100.5,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF0C2E17">
    <ListBoxItem Content="CA" Height="21" Width="236"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Order" Height="21" Width="236"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Year" Height="21" Width="236"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Most ordered products" Height="21" Width="236"/>
</ListBox>
```

The thing is when I put my listBox at the very top, or the very bottom of the page, it gets enabled, but if I move it anywhere else, it gets disabled. I've been searching for a solution for a while and I can't find a thing. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution myself !

Using the attribute Source works just fine. I've put an imageBox in front of my main Window without noticing. I removed it and it works !

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the following:

```
Topmost="True"
```

Comment: I can't use it because, in Modern UI for wpf,  pages are used not windows.